# Xcode 11 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass' missing in menu

Tags: core-data, xcode11

I cannot get Xcode 11 to update CoreData sublasses.
There used to be a menu item 'Editor' > 'Create NSManagedObject Subclass' which does not exist anymore.

Now when I make changes in the core data schema file, existing files like `MyModel+CoreDataProperties.swift` do not get updated automatically either.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my humble experience, the data model editor must be the active window, usually something I achieve by selecting the `.xcdatamodeld` file in the Project Navigator

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ok, a combination of 'Clean Build Folder' *and* closing an reopening the project did the trick.